# Is it possible to get the Value of a changed property instead of only its Name when implementing INPC?

Tags: c#-4.0, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

I am using `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that my domain objects in a class library can notify progress of their execution methods. This is not related to WPF or DataBinding situations.

I have read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about `PropertyChanged` event and the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` has only a `PropertyName` property:

> A `PropertyChanged` event is raised when a property is changed on a component. A `PropertyChangedEventArgs` object specifies the NAME of the property that changed.
>
> `PropertyChangedEventArgs` provides the `PropertyName` property to get the NAME of the property that changed.

Problem is: I need to get the VALUE of the changed property, not its name, so I ask:

> Is there a way to get the value of a property in `PropertyChanged` event args?

(because if not, I think I'll have to create myself a `ReportProgress` event, similar to `BackgroundWorker` class, is that right?)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `sender.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(sender, null)`

Comment: Why would you you NPC for this? Use `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>`.

Comment: @mikez Unfortunately I am using C# 4.0 in VisualStudio 2010... Do you know any other alternative to INPC then? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still get the value by handling `PropertyChanged`. Just use the name to go back and get the value.

```
someObject.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
    var value = sender.GetType()
        .GetProperty(e.PropertyName)
        .GetValue(sender, null);
    // do something with value?
};
```

Check out [`Type.GetProperty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`PropertyInfo.GetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).